# rails 3 link to delete - The action :id could not be found for controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am working on a rails 3 app, and i am trying to link_to a delete path. It seems pretty straightforward, and my routes look like this

```
namespace :admin do
    resources :users, :except => :destroy do
      ...
      delete :delete_contacts, :on => :collection
    end
end
```

and my controller looks like this

```
class Admin::UsersController < ApplicationController

  ...

  def delete_contacts
    user = User.find(params[:user_id])

    user.contacts.destroy_all

    redirect_to edit_admin_user_path(current_user.id)
    flash[:notice] = "Successfully deleted #{user.name} contacts"
  end
end
```

and my current link_to looks like this

```
<%= link_to delete_contacts_admin_users_path(user_id: @user.id), method: :delete, data: { confirm: 'Are you sure you want to delete this users Contacts?' }, remote: true do %>
      <h4 style="color: #BF3430;"><i class="material-icons">delete_forever</i> Delete Contacts</h4>
<% end %>
```

I have tried the routes both with and without the `:on => :collection`, and i seem to keep getting the same error:

**ERROR**

```
Started DELETE "/admin/users/955/delete_properties/" for 127.0.0.1 at 2018-01-17 17:58:34 -0800
Processing by Admin::UsersController#delete_properties as JS
  Parameters: {"id"=>"955"}
```

But the link that is made, `/admin/users/delete_properties/?user_id=955` , seems like just the link needed?

Does anyone see what I'm doing wrong here? this is pretty straightforward, I'm not sure why it's not behaving the way i'm thinking it should. Any help is much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Personally, I think I would have done:

```
namespace :admin do
  resources :users, :except => :destroy do
    delete :delete_contacts, :on => :member
  end
end
```

Which would give you:

```
delete_contacts_admin_user DELETE /admin/users/:id/delete_contacts(.:format)  admin/users#delete_contacts
```

Then, you could do:

```
<%= link_to delete_contacts_admin_user_path(@user) ... %>
```

My thinking is that you're working with a particular `user` and so using a `member` path instead of a `collection` path, IMO, seems a little more natural.

Of course, you'd have to change your action slightly:

```
class Admin::UsersController < ApplicationController

  ...

  def delete_contacts
    user = User.find(params[:id])

    user.contacts.destroy_all

    redirect_to edit_admin_user_path(current_user.id)
    flash[:notice] = "Successfully deleted #{user.name} contacts"
  end

  ...

end
```

That `edit_admin_user_path` may be munged based on this, so you might have to look at the route for that, too (and possibly others, as well).

Comment: that makes perfect sense to me, and i just added that, but i'm still getting the same error: `AbstractController::ActionNotFound (The action '955' could not be found for Admin::UsersController):` . to me it looks like rails thinks the `admin/users/:id` is a controller action (which is why i tried the `on: :collection` originally). For example, when i refresh the page, the notice is there, the resource has been deleted, etc, rails just get's tripped up on it. the route it generates in the html is `/admin/users/955/delete_contacts/` which seems like it should work

Comment: Curious. Perhaps you could add the error from console to your question?

Comment: Sorry, I was thinking more of the stack trace to see exactly what's happening.

Comment: Yeah, as you can see, your `delete_properties` action is working just fine now. It's the `Started DELETE "/admin/users/955/edit/"` that's failing. Which is a different problem.

Comment: i was more or less able to figure it out by removing the `remote: true` from the `link_to`